# Kак одной командой преобразовать многомерный список строк в многомерный список чисел?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Eсть список вида:

```
[['4', '45120'], ['52520', '52', '445', '778'], ['5785699', '789', '550000', '7'], 
 ['89952', '8753', '7878', '8'], ['8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '255', '16']]
```

Как преобразовать все строки в числа одной командой?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Для данного конкретного массива:

```
In [89]: [list(map(int, x)) for x in lst]
Out[89]:
[[4, 45120],
 [52520, 52, 445, 778],
 [5785699, 789, 550000, 7],
 [89952, 8753, 7878, 8],
 [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 255, 16]]
```

PS это решение не будет работать, если будет более глубокая вложенность - для таких случаев можно воспользоваться [рекурсивной функцией](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/608684).