# Как применить функцию ко всем элементам списка (произвольной вложенности)

Tags: python, алгоритм, list, список

Отвечая на [данный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608656/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-python-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9), я заинтересовался более универсальным решением...

Есть список произвольной вложенности, например:

```
['1','2', ['1',['2','4',['5','6']]],'7','8']
```

Необходимо применить функцию ко всем элементам списка (включая все вложенные), сохранив при этом его структуру.

Например преобразовать все элементы в числа и возвести их в квадрат, чтобы получилось:

```
[1, 4, [1, [4, 16, [25, 36]]], 49, 64]
```

Я опубликовал свой вариант решения, но мне было бы интересно увидеть альтернативные (более интересные) решения.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Чтобы поместу изменить, не создавая новые списки ([поиск в глубину—depth-first search (DFS)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83)):

```
def apply_nested(func, lst, isatom=lambda item: not isinstance(item, list)):
    for i, item in enumerate(lst):
        if isatom(item):
            lst[i] = func(item)
        else:
            apply_nested(func, item, isatom)
```

Здесь `isatom()` предикат определяет, что является неразрывным элементом (атомом) для заданного алгоритма: `apply_nested(func, lst)` вызывает `func` функцию для каждого атома в (глубоковложенном) списке `lst`. Похожее решение: [`flatten_gen()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/584650/23044).

Легко создать нерекурсивный вариант ([поиск в ширину—breadth-first search (BFS), если использовать `deque.popleft()`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83)):

```
def apply_nested(func, lst, isatom=lambda item: not isinstance(item, list)):
    stack = [lst]
    while stack:
        lst = stack.pop()
        for i, item in enumerate(lst):
            if isatom(item):
                lst[i] = func(item)
            else:
                stack.append(item)
```

Пример:

```
>>> nested = ['1','2', ['1',['2','4',['5','6']]],'7','8']
>>> apply_nested(lambda atom: int(atom)**2, nested)
>>> nested 
[1, 4, [1, [4, 16, [25, 36]]], 49, 64]
```

Аналогично, можно определить функции, которые возвращают новые значения, не изменяя ввода (DFS):

```
def map_nested(func, lst, isatom=lambda item: not isinstance(item, list)):
    return [func(item) if isatom(item) else map_nested(func, item, isatom)
            for item in lst]
```

Нерекурсивный вариант:

```
def map_nested(func, lst, isatom=lambda item: not isinstance(item, list)):
    result = []
    stack = [(lst, result)]
    while stack:
        lst, new_lst = stack.pop()
        for item in lst:
            if isatom(item):
                new_lst.append(func(item))
            else: # item is a sublist (collection)
                sublist = []
                new_lst.append(sublist)
                stack.append((item, sublist))
    return result
```

Пример:

```
>>> map_nested(lambda atom: int(atom)**2, nested))
[1, 4, [1, [4, 16, [25, 36]]], 49, 64]
```

Answer (score 10):

Сложно что-то выдумать - в вашем решении уже вроде все есть. Однако, можно попробовать внести пару (ненужных?) изменений + функция в одну строку. Большую функцию тоже можно при желании разместить в 1 строку, однако это уже будет чересчур:

```
import timeit


def map_nested(lst, func=lambda x: x, forbidden_types=(str, int)):
    container_type = type(lst)
    if hasattr(lst, '__iter__') and type(lst) not in forbidden_types:
        return container_type(map_nested(item, func) for item in lst)
    else:
        try:
            return func(lst)
        except:
            return lst


def map_nested_1line(lst, func=lambda x: x):
    return [map_nested_1line(item, func) for item in lst] if type(lst) is list else func(lst)
```

**UPDATE:**
Утро вечера мудренее и подумав я родил нерекурсивный вариант этой функции. Нерекурсивный хорош тем, что не упадет на длинных и сильно вложенных списках на [ОС с ограничением на длину рекурсии](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3194553/1185696). Плох тем, что очень медленный. Суть нерекурсивного решения в том, что в специальный массив заносится порядок входа и выхода во вложенные списки. Находим вложенный массив - заносим указатель на него + индекс в спец. хранилище. Выходим из него - указатель и индекс извлекаем.

```
# Also non-recursive. Yay!
def map_nested_inplace(lst, func=lambda x: x, forbidden_types=(str, int)):
    # forbidden_types не используется
    processed_elements = 0
    # assert type(lst) is list # blah-blah
    current_container = lst
    containers_repo = [[current_container, 0]]
    # До тех пор, пока не были обработаны все списки и под-списки
    while len(containers_repo) != 0:
        while True:
            try:
                # Следующий элемент в текущем списке. 
                # Может быть как числом, так и новым под-списком
                next_one = current_container[containers_repo[-1][1]]
                break
            # Исключение означает, что под-список кончился. 
            # Т.к. он кончился, то убираем его из хранилища 
            # и пробуем извлечь следующий элемент
            except IndexError:
                containers_repo.pop()
                if len(containers_repo) == 0:
                    break
                current_container = containers_repo[-1][0]
        if len(containers_repo) != 0:
            if type(next_one) is list:
                # Это под-список, а не число. 
                # Заносим под-список в хранилище и 
                # на следующей итерации открываем уже его
                containers_repo[-1][1] += 1
                current_container = next_one
                containers_repo.append([current_container, 0])
            else:
                current_container[containers_repo[-1][1]] = func(current_container[containers_repo[-1][1]])
                containers_repo[-1][1] += 1
                # ради небольшой проверки
                processed_elements += 1


# set также работает, но непохоже, чтобы он сохранял порядок
lst = ['1', 'an error', ('1', ['2', '4', (5, '6')]), '7', 8]
lst_simple = ['1', '2', ['1', ['2', '4', ['5', '6']]], '7', '8']
lst_another_simple = ['1', '2', ['1', ['2', '4', ['5', '6']], ['6', '6', '6'], ['8', '8']], '7', ['11'], '8']
print(map_nested(lst, lambda x: int(x)**2))
print(map_nested_1line(lst_simple, lambda x: int(x)**2))
print(map_nested_1line([], lambda x: int(x)**2))
map_nested_inplace(lst_another_simple, lambda x: int(x)**2)
print(lst_another_simple)
```

Также немного тестирования:

```
import random
test_array = []
container_tree = [test_array]
current_container = container_tree[-1]
TOTAL_AMOUNT = 10000
NEW_LEVEL_PROBABILITY = 0.5
for i in range(TOTAL_AMOUNT):
    if random.random() >= NEW_LEVEL_PROBABILITY:
        current_container.append([])
        container_tree.append(current_container[-1])
        current_container = current_container[-1]
    elif len(container_tree) > 1:
        current_container = container_tree[-2]
    current_container.append(str(random.randint(0, 20)))

# Для работоспособности рекурсивных методов
# Впрочем, без старта новго потока с threading.stack_size(<Big value>) все равно не будет работать :(
import sys
if sys.getrecursionlimit() < len(container_tree) * 2:
    sys.setrecursionlimit(len(container_tree) * 2)

setup_statement = """from __main__ import test_array, """

# Не используется lambda x**2, потому что 
# в inplace квадраты будут накатываться до тех пор, 
# пока хватит памяти - список для каждого прохода должен генерироваться заново

print(timeit.timeit("map_nested_inplace(test_array)", setup=setup_statement + "map_nested_inplace", number=100))
print(timeit.timeit("map_nested_1line(test_array)", setup=setup_statement + "map_nested_1line", number=100))
print(timeit.timeit("map_nested(test_array)", setup=setup_statement + "map_nested", number=100))

>>> 1.8096923486838081  # Без рекурсии
>>> 0.9477624593712808  # Однострочник
>>> 1.827232542223693  # Большая функция
```

Comment: Спасибо! Очень интересный вариант - изучаю...!

Comment: @MaxU, дописал комментов. Не знаю даже, где может понадобиться нерекурсивная реализация, но если уж начал писать код, становится трудно остановиться.

Comment: всегда хорошо иметь альтернативный вариант на случай если рекурсивный вариант по какой-то причине не будет работать.

Comment: Выглядит усложнённо. Особенно [нерекурсивный вариант можно значительно упростить](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/608981/23044)

Answer (score 9):

Решение:

```
def map_nested(lst, func=lambda x: x):
    assert isinstance(lst, list), '"lst" parameter is NOT a list'
    return [map_nested(lst[i], func)
            if isinstance(lst[i], list)
            else func(lst[i])
            for i in range(len(lst))]
```

Тест:

```
In [154]: lst = ['1', '2', ['1', ['2', '4', ['5', '6']]], '7', '8']

In [155]: map_nested(lst, lambda x: int(x)**2)
Out[155]: [1, 4, [1, [4, 16, [25, 36]]], 49, 64]
```

Answer (score 2):

В голову сразу пришло такое решение

```
def anon(l, func=lambda x: int(x) ** 2):
    for n, i in enumerate(l):
        if type(i) != list:
            l[n] = func(i)
        else:
            anon(i)
    return l

lst = ['1', '2', ['1', ['2', '4', ['5', '6']]], '7', '8']
print(anon(lst))

>>> [1, 4, [1, [4, 16, [25, 36]]], 49, 64]
```