# Python. List Исследование типов элементов во вложенных списках

Tags: python, list, список

Вопрос.
Говорю сразу зачем - домашнее задание.
Дан список, со вложенными списками ( неизвестной глубины вложенности).
Написать алгоритм, который переберет все вложенности, дойдет до элементов, и определит, тип каждого из них.
Список будет, приюлизительно таким

```
a = [
    [
        [[1,2,3],["a","b","c"]],
        [[3,4,5],["d","e","f"]]
    ],
    [
        [[123,print,None],["aa","bb","cc"]],
        [[-10,3.14,"London"],[100,int,"qwerty"]]
    ]
]
```

моя задача определить тип элементов и произвести надо ними, некоторые действия, в зависимости от типа.

```
if element == int or float:
    print(element*2)
elif element == str:
    print(element*2)
elif element == None:
    print('none')
else:
    print('element is built in function')
```

Но вот, как "докопаться" до элементов, вложенных списков - торможу.
Очевидно, каким то рекурсивным методом при условии `if element == list`
Прошу помощи зала!

Comment: Похожий вопрос: [Как применить функцию ко всем элементам списка (произвольной вложенности)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608684/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8) - там вы можете найти и рекурсивную и нерекурсивную реализации

Comment: Дуже дякую!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример рекурсивной реализации:

```
def f(element):
    if isinstance(element, (list, tuple, set)):
        for sub_element in element:
            f(sub_element)
    elif isinstance(element, (int, float)):
        print(element**2)
    elif isinstance(element, (str, bytes, bytearray)):
        print(element.upper())
    elif element is None:
        print("NONE")
    else:
        print("OTHER")

a = [
    [
        [[1,2,3],["a","b","c"]],
        [[3,4,5],["d","e","f"]]
    ],
    [
        [[123,print,None],["aa","bb","cc"]],
        [[-10,3.14,"London"],[100,int,"qwerty"]]
    ]
]

f(a)

>>>
1
4
9
A
B
C
9
16
25
D
E
F
15129
OTHER
NONE
AA
BB
CC
100
9.8596
LONDON
10000
OTHER
QWERTY
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Сейчас попробую