# Переполнение стека в рекурсии

Tags: python, многопоточность, рекурсия

```
import os
import operator
import sys
import time
import threading

timer = 0
start_time = time.time()
sys.setrecursionlimit(2**20)
result = []
data = []

with open("14.in") as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append([int(x) for x in line.split()])

number_of_point = (int(data[0][0]))
number_of_edge = (int(data[1][0]))
n = number_of_point

fup = [0 for i in range(number_of_point + 1)]
tin = [0 for i in range(number_of_point + 1)]
used = [False for i in range(number_of_point + 1)]
matrica = [[] for i in range(number_of_point + 1)]

dic1 = dict()
dic2 = dict()
dic3 = dict()
dic4 = dict()

for i in range(2, number_of_edge + 2):
    if data[i][1] not in matrica[data[i][0]]:
        matrica[data[i][0]].append(data[i][1])

    if data[i][0] not in matrica[data[i][1]]:
        matrica[data[i][1]].append(data[i][0])

    f = tuple(data[i])
    q = (data[i][1], data[i][0])

    if f or q not in dic1:
        dic3[f] = True
        dic4[q] = True
    else:
        dic3[f] = False
        dic4[q] = False

    dic1[i - 1] = f
    k = (data[i][0], data[i][1])
    dic2[k] = i - 1


def main():
    find_bridges()
    result1 = result
    result1.sort()
    print(result1)
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))


def dfs(v, p=-1):
    used[v] = True
    global timer
    tin[v] = timer
    fup[v] = timer
    timer += 1

    for i in range(0, len(matrica[v])):
        to = matrica[v][i]
        if to == p:
            continue

        if used[to]:
                fup[v] = min(fup[v], tin[to])
        else:
            dfs(to, v)
            fup[v] = min(fup[v], fup[to])
            if (fup[to] > tin[v]):
                IS_BRIDGE(v, to)


def find_bridges():
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        if not used[i]:
            dfs(i)


def IS_BRIDGE(s1, s2):
    temp1 = (s1, s2)
    temp2 = (s2, s1)

    if temp1 in dic1.values():
        if dic3.get(temp1) or dic3.get(temp1):
            k = (dic2.get(temp1))
            result.append(k)
    else:
        if dic3.get(temp2) or dic4.get(temp2):
            k = (dic2.get(temp2))
            result.append(k)

threading.stack_size(67108864)
thread = threading.Thread(target=main)
thread.start()
main()
```

Вот программа.Задача состоит в нахождении мостов в мультиграфе. Алгоритм основан на рекурсии. До 10000 тыс ребер работает все нормально. Но, если больше, то переполняется стек.

```
threading.stack_size(67108864) 
thread = threading.Thread(target=main)
thread.start()
```

Нашел вот это в инете. Помогло, но теперь стало выводить какие то лишние цифры в ответе, и цифры которые вообще за пределом возможного ответа(ответ берется из словаря, там такого ключа просто нет).
Если просто увеличить `sys.setrecursionlimit(2**20)` до макс размера не помогает. А вот если написать 3 строки (которые thread), то программа хотя бы работает при 10000 ребер и больше. Но выводиться как и правильные ответы, так и неправильные. Так же в ответе  значения, которые есть в словаре, но они не подходят по ответу, а при отсутствии `thread` все верно выводится, но при этом должно быть меньше 10000 ребер.Также стоит добавить, что при некоторых тестах, даже если данные входные большие, а мостов оказывается мало, то и при thread ответ выводится верный,однако если мостов много, то выводиться верные ответы, неверные и еще значения,которые никак не могут быть (таких нет в словаре)/

Comment: Дополнить вопрос вы можете кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/782162/edit). Перенесите комментарий и поправте формат.

Comment: поправьте текст вопроса

Comment: Изменил,постарался все правильно описать

Comment: Теперь нужно еще форматирование поправить.

Comment: зачем вы `main()` в двух местах запускаете?

Comment: если убрать ласт main() то ничего не происходит

Comment: Понял, почему так происходит. Нет синхронизации потоков, может кто подскажет, как здесь это сделать

Comment: @ВладМосковкинн до того как ещё один поток добавили у вас один вызов `main()` был? Избавьтесь от глобального состояния. Пишите тесты для вспомогательных функций и для конечного результата на разном вводе. Замените рекурсию явным стеком. Не используйте потоков без необходимости. [пример кода рекурсивный в не рекурсивный вариант превращается](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/608981/23044)