# Как обойти все элементы (применить к ним метод) итерируемого объекта неизвестной глубины вложенности на Python

Tags: python

Есть задача, сама по себе не очень стандартная (не нагуглил ничего похожего), определить, является ли итерируемый объект совершенно пустым (completely empty).

Привожу текст задачи:

> You need to figure if a wellfounded and wellsized iterable is
>   completely empty.
>
> An iterable x0 is wellfounded if there is no infinite sequence
>   x1,x2,x3...such that... in x3 in x2 in x1 in x0 (where in is meant
>   iteratively, x(n+1) will be encountered while iterating through xn ).
>
> A wellfounded iterable is wellsized if it has only finitely many
>   iterable elements, and all of them are wellsized.
>
> A wellfounded iterable is completely empty when all its elements are
>   completely empty.
>
> Some consequences of the above definitions:
>
> - any empty iterable is completely empty
> - a non-iterable is never completely empty
> - the only wellfounded string is    ''  , and it is completely empty  bytes, and (possibly nested) tuples/frozensets of them are always
>     wellfounded and wellsized
> - {'': 'Nonempty'}   is a wellfounded and completely empty iterable
>     after    c=[];c.append(c), c is a non-wellfounded iterable
>     itertools.repeat(())  is wellfounded but not wellsized
>     itertools.repeat(5)   is wellfounded and wellsized
>
> Input: A wellfounded and wellsized iterable.
>
> Output: A bool

Вижу для себя две проблемы, в решении которых гугл не помог:

1. Метод обхода всех элементов итерируемого объекта, представляющих собой iterable со вложенными iterable и так далее;
2. неполное понимание определения completely empty в отношении итерируемых объектов различных типов.

Comment: Приведите небольшой пример данных (объекта)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как применить функцию ко всем элементам списка (произвольной вложенности)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/608684/23044)

Comment: матрица -- это двумерный (прямоугольный) объект, поэтому не используйте это слова для объектов "неизвестной глубины вложенности". *Что значит в вашем случае "совершенно пустым"?* (конкретный пример стоит привести) На входе у вас повторно итерируемые объекты (такие как последовательности) или за один раз исчерпываются (итераторы)?

Comment: Ошибочно полагал, что термин 'completely empty' является устойчивым и общеизвестным. Даю определение от источника задачи (checkio.org):any empty iterable is completely empty
    a non-iterable is never completely empty
    the only wellfounded string is    ''  , and it is completely empty
       {'': 'Nonempty'}   is a wellfounded and completely empty iterable. И -да, на входе именно повторно итерируемые объекты (вложенные списки, кортежи, словари с неопределенной глубиной вложенности)

Comment: Нажмите кнопку [edit] и добавьте в вопрос необходимые определения (подсказка: если термин определён прямо в задаче, то вероятно он не является "устойчивым и общеизвестным" -- иначе не пришлось бы определение давать)

Answer (score 1):

```
def empty_tree(input_list):
    for item in input_list:
        if not isinstance(item, list) or not empty_tree(item):
             return False
    return True
```

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1593797/10090254

Другим путем с более жесткими проверками:

```
import collections
def completely_empty(array):
    if type(array) == str:
        return True if array == '' else False
    if type(array) == list:
        return True if len(array) == 0 else \
               all([completely_empty(i) for i in array])
    if type(array) == dict:
        return True if len(array) == 0 or \
               (len(array.keys()) == 1 and '' in array) else False
    if type(array) == tuple:
        return completely_empty(list(array))
    try:
        array.__getitem__(0)
    except IndexError:
        return True
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    return all([completely_empty(i) for i in array]) \
           if isinstance(array, collections.abc.Iterable) \ # на старых версиях возможны ошибки, нужно заменить collections.abc.Iterable на collections.Iterable
           else False
```

Comment: Споткнулось на "assert completely_empty(['']) == True; 
    assert completely_empty([[],[{'':'No WAY'}]]) == True". Тоесть пустая строка и словарь с ключом '' .Добавить проверку на эти условия - дело техники, но проверка ответа предполагает неизвестные конкретные входные данные, соответствующие общему условию. Камень преткновения - именно оно (' to figure if a wellfounded and wellsized iterable is completely empty.')

Comment: @IvanStepanoff добавил новый вариант, попробуйте его.

Comment: К сожалению, SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character (<MYCODE>, line 20), ?, ? Пытаюсь понять, что не устраивает интерпретатор. Мне самому непонятны обратные слэши в условиях. Пока не встречал нигде ничего подобного...

Comment: @IvanStepanoff обратные слэши - просто перевод строки(для удобночитаемости кода). Уберите в 20 строке комментарий `# ...` и измените там же `collections.abc.Iterable` на `collections.Iterable`